# Programmatic access to a Subversion repository

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have to write code to send periodic mail to the associated project member if code committed to SVN is more than a week old.

My problem is this: I don't know how access a repository to extract information for the entire project such as the date of the most recent commit to a given project. I am thinking of saving this in a file for use in my Java project.

Comment: I removed the tags for user interfaces (TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN) because you want programmatic access and for Windows 7 as that almost certainly has nothing to do with the solution. I suppose you are actually running VisualSVN server, so I left that in, but if your solution uses the SVN protocol (directly or via the `svn` command), the server implementation is also irrelevant.

Comment: Your ‘project’ is presumably everything under a certain node in the Subversion directory structure. You might just start `svn info` to get information about that. Using an API to access the repository is probably a lot more complicated – but I haven’t studied that – but nor have you.

Answer (score -1):

If this is in Java as you mention, look at [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).  It's not immediately obvious what you want to do, so refer to the [code samples](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_Repository_With_SVNKit) on their wiki for example code.

Comment: thanks patrick i have installed svnkit and by using cmd "svn username pwd info path/url" and then use index of to "last changed date" and add it to mail sending code.